# Api not being connected, receiving error message

Tags: java, android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I purchased a code from a site, now am having a runtime error executing it. I think it has to do with the url not being formatted correctly.

```
public class ApiRequest {

public static void Call_Api (final Context context, String url, JSONObject jsonObject,
                             final Callback callback){

    final String [] urlsplit=url.split("/");
    Log.d(Variables.tag,urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1]);

    if(jsonObject!=null)
    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],jsonObject.toString());

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],response.toString());

                    if(callback!=null)
                    callback .Responce(response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Api run timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(callback!=null)
              callback .Responce(error.toString());

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
}
}
```

The url it's supposed to receive is like this, https://example.com/API/.
I seriously doubt it has to do with the backslashes, tried changing the url to non trailing slashes, but it isn't working. Can anyone help me out?

Checked for the error/stack trace as one user commented. and found this is the problem.

```
D/thumkaindex.php?p=discover: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

So I have added the JSON conversion code. The app accesses the api from a domain, but the location of the page is very wrong. it's location is, example.com/API/index.php, the app name is thumka, but I don't see where the D/thumkaindex.php is from.

This is where the url is being parsed. There is something wrong with the code?

```
public class ApiRequest {

public static void Call_Api (final Context context, String url, JSONObject jsonObject,
                             final Callback callback){

    final String [] urlsplit=url.split("/");
    Log.d(Variables.tag,urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1]);

    if(jsonObject!=null)
    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],jsonObject.toString());

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],response.toString());

                    if(callback!=null)
                    callback .Responce(response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Api run timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(callback!=null)
              callback .Responce(error.toString());

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
 }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, I don't know how these functions work. any light on that?. what could lead to error?

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Can you also add the error/stack trace?

Comment: what's an error/stack trace?. where do I see that?

Comment: E/Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps